Can I insert a page with pdfpages when the text naturally causes a pagebreak?
Quite simply, I want to insert a page using pdfpages, but instead of causing a pagebreak at the position in the text where I call the command, I want it to wait until the text would break naturally - insert the page - and then continue.
It seems this would be a normal usecase for many things, no? Wait for the next pagebreak then do x.

probably \afterpage{\include...} does what you want (afterpage package)

For a single page you can also make a  a figure float  with the [t] option and place it somewhere that will be for sure in the next page,   and then include the page in the float as a normal image, i.e., \includegraphics[with=xx cm, page=23]{foo.pdf}. Of course, this will not work if there  are previous pending floats that could  prevent the float move to the top.
